# How to detect button presses with a 74HC595 shift register?

Tags: arduino-uno, button, shift-register

Is there a way I can have my arduino uno differentiate between pushbuttons that are wired through a shift register and detect when each are pressed or not? I found [this](https://infectedbytes.com/2016/07/arduino-shiftin.html) tutorial for the 74HC165 but I'm not sure it's applicable to the 74HC595.

Answer (score 1):

The [74HC595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls041i/scls041i.pdf) is a *deserializer* while the 74HC165 is a *serializer*. This means the former consumes a serial datastream and provides all data bits in parallel on dedicated data lines. While the latter consumes parallel data and converts it to a serial datastream.

To scan buttons you want to have parallel input data, where each switch is attached to a single data line. Then you serialize the data to reduce the amount of required Arduino inputs. This method is well explained in the mentioned tutorial.

As the 74HC595 is a deserializer it is not really applicable here. Instead you could use it to drive multiple outputs through a serial interface (see https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut as an example).

Comment: Well, it's not completely true about it's not applicable. It can be used as outputs for scanning buttons. However it has some pitfalls